# How to destroy the cookie of treeview on logout?

Tags: jquery

I set the option `persist` to cookie in my `treeview` function ( treeview plugin ). How to destroy the `cookie` when logging out ? I tried `unset($_COOKIE['rememberme']);` but the menu is restored when logging !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following javascript to set the exipration date of the cookie well into the past, thereby making it inaccessible.

```
document.cookie = 'rememberme=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unsetting the cookie like this

```
document.cookie = rememberme+ '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```