# What makes a treeview cookie expired or cleared?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I built a tree menu with treeview :

```
$("#browser").treeview({
                collapsed: true,
                animated: "fast",
                prerendered: false,
                persist: "cookie",
                cookieId: "rememberme"
            });
```

What can make the cookie cleared or expired ?

Comment: document.cookie = 'rememberme=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

Comment: seems like you had asked the same question sometime back as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683952/how-to-destroy-the-cookie-of-treeview-on-logout . Doesn't that handle what you are asking for ?

Comment: I commented this code in my project , though the menu is collapsed after 3 clicks which calls each time treeview function !

Comment: how is collapse related to cookie expiration?

Comment: it is related because persistence is lost.

Comment: if you check https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview/blob/master/jquery.treeview.js out, serialize method stores the options along with cookie. If you pass the name of cookie in options then it will use/update that cookie

Comment: Can you write code of how to serialize ?

Comment: treeview js has serialize method, you need not do anything for that